# RGB color space conversion to HSV color space in Google Earth Engine using Sentinel 2 images

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am trying to convert RGB colour space to HSV colour space in GEE. I am using function rgbToHsv() for the same. I am able to get results for Landsat 8 images but not for Sentinel 2 images. The study area is the same for both of them.

Using Landsat 8 images:

```
var col = landsat.filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER',15)).
             filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31').filterBounds(pn);
print(col);
var img = col.first();
Map.addLayer(img,
imageVisParam, 'RGB'
);
Map.addLayer(img,
imageVisParam2, 'FCC'
);
var hsv = img.select(['B4','B3','B2']).rgbToHsv();
print(hsv,'HSV');
Map.addLayer(hsv,{},'HSV');
```

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/aea87858ab48b64f5b3981b3d7446a83

Using Sentinel 2 images:

```
print(col);
var img = col.median();
Map.addLayer(img,imageVisParam,'RGB');
Map.addLayer(img,imageVisParam2,'FCC');
var hsv = img.select(['B4','B3','B2']).rgbToHsv();
print(hsv);
Map.addLayer(hsv,{},'HSV');
```

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/75ba3f6db7ecc497f25111547816df67

Answer (score 2):

Sentinel 2 reflectance is scaled by 10000. Just divide by 10000 and it should look as expected.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/dd9fcdc700fe7b057fc430f9749407c3